# How to send parent trace id and span using Grpc Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc

I want to perform request between services, stream and unary.
I use proto 3 and java/springboot.
My code is following:

```
@Service
public class GrpcService {

    @GrpcClient("square")
    private SquareRpcGrpc.SquareRpcBlockingStub blockingStub;

    @GrpcClient("square")
    private SquareRpcGrpc.SquareRpcStub asyncStub;


    public Object getSquareResponseUnary(int number){
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, number)
                .mapToObj(i -> Input.newBuilder().setNumber(i).build())
                .map(this.blockingStub::findSquareUnary)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Output::getNumber,
                        Output::getResult
                ));
    }

    public Object getSquareResponseStream(int number){
        CompletableFuture<Map<Integer, Integer>> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        OutputStreamingResponse outputStreamingResponse = new OutputStreamingResponse(
                new HashMap<>(),
                completableFuture
        );
        StreamObserver<Input> squareBiStream = this.asyncStub.findSquareBiStream(outputStreamingResponse);
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, number)
                .mapToObj(i -> Input.newBuilder().setNumber(i).build())
                .forEach(squareBiStream::onNext);
        squareBiStream.onCompleted();
        return completableFuture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using spring-boot, you can use [spring-cloud-sleuth](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth) and gRPC interceptor to do this.

- Client

```java
@Slf4j
class CustomForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT> extends ClientInterceptors.CheckedForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT> {

    @Override
    protected void checkedStart(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) throws Exception {
        // ... get trace info from trace context and put trace info into header
        headers.add("traceId", "TRACE_ID")
        delegate().start(listener, headers);
    }    
}
```

- Server

```java
public class CustomServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall, Metadata metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
        // ... get trace info from metadata
        String traceId = metadata.get("traceId");
        // put into trace context
        return new CustomServerCallListener<>(listener);
    }
}
```